# perforce on sourceforge

Tags: perforce, sourceforge

Has anyone set up a perforce server on [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net)? Is this even possible? Any tips appreciated! I'd like to investigate it and possibly move from Subversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look into http://info.perforce.com/FreeTrial_Cloud_Offer.html

Answer (score 1):

No.

SourceForge isn't a free-for-all where you can run whatever you want... You can only use the tools they provide.

Perforce is a heavily server-based VCS, so you need to be able to run the Perforce server somewhere centrally.

If you want to use Perforce you'll have to find a provider that offers Perforce, or a straight  server, so that you can install your own programs.